# Finding equivalent of imagemagick morphology command with opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, imagemagick

I have an image with horizontal lines in it. An approach that I found that works somewhat well is to use imagemagick to morphology like this.

```
convert orig.jpg -morphology close:1 "1x7: 1,0,0,0,0,0,1" final.jpg
```

It is running one iteration of morphology with 1x7 kernel

I'm trying to find equivalent of this in opencv python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command is performing the CLOSING Morphological Operation on the image which can be translated to OpenCV as:

```
kernel = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=np.uint8)  # 1x7: 1,0,0,0,0,0,1
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, 
                           cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, # morphology close:1
                           kernel)
```

Comment: I get error `Assertion failed (_kernel.type() == CV_8U) in MorphFilter, file /home/guru/opencv-2.4.10/modules/imgproc/src/morph.cpp, line 791
mitre1.jpg /home/guru/opencv-2.4.10/modules/imgproc/src/morph.cpp:791: error: (-215) _kernel.type() == CV_8U in function MorphFilter` while doing this in opencv using the snippet you provided. if I change `np.array([[1,0,0,0,0,0,1]])` to `np.ones((1,1))` then it works fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry @Anthony missed something obvious there, Edited.

Comment: Thanks! that worked! however, I'm not getting results anywhere close to what imagemagik provides. [original img](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qifnldrd5wpi0vh/mitre1.crop.warped1.jpg?dl=0), [converted from imagemagik](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yj34ot1xmc619q6/mitre1.crop.im.jpg?dl=0), [converted from opencv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tjdo1i0pbiiyuc5/mitre1.crop.closed.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: FWIW i got the imagemagik command from here http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?p=92969#p92969 which explains what the command is doing in detail

Comment: Oh that was really Helpful.

Comment: Edited @Anthony

Comment: It still doesnt have the same effect. Are you getting same results?

Comment: Yeah I got pretty same results, I can attach them with the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136754/discussion-between-anthony-and-zdar).